# SSRS Revert to parent security

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have 50+ report parts which have specific AD Groups assigned to them as Browser.

This is so only certain people have access to the data.

To accomplish this, on the security settings I changed it by clicking 'Edit Item Security'

This resulted in SSRS not inheriting the security anymore (i.e If I put an individuals AD name for the project folder they would be given access to everything)

So all my report parts have individual groups as it stands, the problems is I now need to give 1 individual access to everything.

With the current set up this would mean adding them 1 by 1 to all the report parts however there is a button called 'Revert to parent security'.

My question is, if i click this will it remove all the individual group security settings I have applied or will it allow me to add 1 person to all whilst leaving all the others the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Books Online ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180265.aspx ) 
`Revert to Parent Security` will remove all the individual group security settings

> Click to reset the security settings to that of the immediate parent
>   folder. If inheritance is unbroken throughout the report server folder
>   hierarchy, the security settings of the top-level folder, Home, are
>   used.

In your scenario, it seems that you have to add user individually to every secured item. You could do it programmatically using Reporting Services scripting host (see http://msftrsprodsamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SS2008%21Script%20Samples%20%28Reporting%20Services%29 for some sample scripts) or Powershell ( see [Using Powershell to set user permissions in Reporting Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066869/using-powershell-to-set-user-permissions-in-reporting-services) for a sample)